# Recompilation issue with in-memory tables

Tags: sql-server

In our high-loaded OLTP processing we're using permanent in-memory tables like temporary tables (similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017, case C). But, under a low load we found very big number of recompilations in stored procedures caused by the reason '2 - Statistics changed'. Number of rows in these tables varies from 0 to 50-100 each execution. There is no way to disable auto update statistics on in-memory tables. Also, an option 'KEEPFIXED PLAN' cannot be applied in subqueries like this:

```
if exists(
    select 1 from dbo.mytable option (KEEPFIXED PLAN)
)
begin
    select 1
end
```

Any ideas, how can we avoid excessive recompilations?

Comment: Do the recompilations cause performance problems? Or you just don't like that the count is high? And why do you think the option needs to be in the subquery instead of at the end of the statement? It applies to a query/plan, not a table.

Comment: Yes, we have performance problems - an operation that runs under 150 msec under 50 tps slowed down to 2 sec under 1 tps. Processor load is low, just a duration of execution increased. Now we added some thousands of rows to each table to avoid recompilations, but it's not a very elegant solution.

Comment: You add data to avoid recompilations? What exactly did you do to determine that recompilations *caused* the performance problem?

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, thank you very much for your suggestion - solution found. It's not perfect - we have to rewrite a lot of code, but it works. We have to change an 'if' operator to a query, so we can apply hints this way:

```
declare @exists int
select @exists = 1 where exists (select 1 from dbo.MyTable) option (KEEPFIXED PLAN)
if @exists = 1
begin
    select 'exists!!!'
end
else
begin
    select 'not exists...'
end
```